# Jenkins Post actions fails but stage not marked in red

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, stage

Maybe is a stupid question but is a bit weird.
Does anyone knows why in jenkins with the post declarative actions, if there is an error there the "Stage" of the declarative post actions is not marked in red?
For example I have a pipeline of 5 stages and a declarative post actions.

[image]

such declarative postaction makes a commit in a git repo so sometimes when the github repo is down they can also fail (There is a retry mechanism but is not the key of the question)
When the fail the box is still on green. The pipeline itself is marked as failure and in red, but not this box.
[image]
[image]
does someone have any idea why?

thanks in advance